# Safari Mac OSX Backspace Issues

Tags: c#, javascript, html, silverlight, safari

Is there anyone out there who knows how to handle the behavior of Safari Web Browser that sets the current page to the previous page whenever users were pressing backspace key? I'm currently experiencing this issue on Mac OSX Lion 10.7.2 and a silverlight application whenever our users were trying to correct fields using the backspace/Delete key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem in the past too. I spent a good week or so trying to come up with a solution, and eventually the best way to work around this problem (I never found a "fix" so to speak) was the following:

1. Suspend all of the backspace key down events using Javascript. Don't allow any backspace events to reach the Silverlight container. This will mean that Silverlight never takes you to the previous page any more, but you also won't be able to delete any text in a text field! Point 2 explains how to work around this.
2. Attach a `KeyUp` event handler to the `RootVisual` of your Silverlight control. `KeyEventArgs`' original source is a TextField and the key itself was `Key.Back`, then we must delete some text inside of the textbox manually. We do this by looking at the TextBox's `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties. `SelectionStart` gives you the location you want to delete from, and `SelectionLength` gives you how many characters you want to delete. Finally, you need to work out the correct location of where the cursor should be now. This should just be equal to the `SelectionStart` property's value.

There is a flaw with this approach. Because we have to manually listen to `KeyUp` events, the `Key.Back` `KeyUp` event is only fired when the backspace key is released. This means that if you are using Safari and hold backspace down, only one character will be deleted. You will need to release backspace and press it again to delete another character. This is a small price to pay in my opinion though, considering the alternatives are to view the previous page or not handle backspace at all!

It's worth noting that all of this can be Mac/Safari specific. You can use `HtmlPage.BrowserInformation.UserAgent` to find the browser type, and only attach the `RootVisual_KeyUp` handler if the browser is Safari. If you only suspend backspace events in javascript in Safari too, this will only have an effect in Mac/Safari, and keep the default functionality for every other browser.

Good Luck! Hope this helps!

Comment: Why did someone down vote my answer? It's a fully working solution that I have been using for while now without any complaints. I outlined why it isn't a perfect solution but I very much doubt you will be able to find one while this Safari/Silverlight bug exists.